# Add height on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I am having a hard time figuring out how to add height to my `div`. Considering this Html :

```
<div id='box'></div> 
<div id='plus' onClick='resize()'>add height</div>
```

I am using this method:
 - on click i read the current height of the div
 - after that i convert the string i get to integer
 - then i add some pixels to the box height

The JS looks like this:

```
   function resize() {
     //get element

     var height=document.getElementById('box').style.height;

     //transform element from string to integer

     height=height.replace("px","");
      height=+height;

      //change height

      var n=height;
      height=n+300+'px';        
   }
```

This should be pretty basic but i can't figure out what i'm missing.

Comment: You can add class on click.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't really understand what do you mean.

Comment: So, you want to enlarge box on every click?

Comment: yes! this is what i want to do

Answer (score 3):

you have not to assign new height to element try below code

```
function resize() { 
 //get element

 var height=document.getElementById('box').style.height;

 //transform element from string to integer

 height=height.replace("px","");
  height=+height;

  //change height

  var n=height;
  height=n+300+'px';        
 document.getElementById('box').style.height = height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this at the end of your code

```
document.getElementById('box').style.height = height
```

Answer (score 2):

See this : **[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wysR/)**

You missed:

```
    document.getElementById('box').style.height = height
```