# Repeating onClick Function - Options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wanting to add 100px(or any number) of CSS height each time the onClick function is called.

click "button1"-CSS adds 100px of height-click "button1" again-CSS adds 100px of height etc.

Is it a Loop? Is it an If statement? Should I give up and pursue being a product manager?

```js
var growButton = document.getElementById("box");
var growParse = parseInt(growButton.style.height, 10);

function grow() {
growButton.style.height = (growParse + 100) + "px";
}
```

```html
    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1" onclick="grow();">Grow</button>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333210/add-height-on-click-with-javascript). It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be a product manager. You only needed to run `growParse` within the function.

```js
var growButton = document.getElementById("box");
var growParse = parseInt(growButton.style.height, 10);


function grow() {
  growParse = parseInt(growButton.style.height, 10);

  growButton.style.height = (growParse + 100) + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>
<button id="button1" onclick="grow();">Grow</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. this is simple and works perfect. I'm wondering if you'd mind helping me understand the function a bit better. I actually don't understand the role of the number 10 as an argument in the parseInt(growButton.style.height, 10). I also am confused why the variabe growParse must be declared globally and within the function too.

Comment: @TheTrain , when you declare it inside the function, then the variable is created everytime the button is clicked. Tha's why i have declared it outside and used it inside. Rearding the parseInt function you can read about it here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt . In general terms it changes the string into integer. The value of the height is 150px initially which is not a number so parseInt changes it into 150 to add it with the old value. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```js
function incHeight() {
        var el = document.getElementById("box");
        var height = el.offsetHeight;
        var newHeight = height + 100;
        el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>
<button id="button1" onclick="incHeight()">Grow</button>
```